# Python : Related to Paramiko

Tags: python

I need to run the windows command "XCOPY" on remote machine.

I am using *paramiko* module to connect to remote machine and run, but I am getting error like *invalid path* even though the path is valid and same command works if I run on remote command prompt manually. But not possible through *paramiko*.

Can anybody help?

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

May be you can get help from:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192808

hava a look.